# How to duplicate a subversion repo without filesystem access?

Tags: svn

I'd like to know if there is an easy way to duplicate a subversion repository without having access to the filesystem.  Meaning that I have read-only access with the HTTP interface.

Basically, I'd like to have my own locally-hosted copy of a repository for an open-source project.  They provide anonymous access to the subversion repo as usual.

I've looked through the docs, and I guess my Google-fu is good enough because I couldn't find any reference to doing something like this.

So basically I want to download all the revisions, and be able to import them into my own repo using svnadmin.

Answer (score 7):

I think you're wanting **`svnsync`**:

```
svnadmin create /localsvn
svnsync init file:///localsvn http://domain/svn
svnsync sync file:///localsvn
```

You'll have to enable the `pre-revprop-change` hook in your local repository or `svnsync` will complain.

But, just repeat the last command as necessary.

Note that `svnsync` commands require URL arguments.

Comment: It's worth noting that svnsync only grabs the necessary changes to bring your repository up to date, so is quite efficient.
Also you must not modify the local repository yourself - just use svnsync.

Comment: Ah, that's very helpful, thanks Jonathan.

Unfortunately, the repo is hitting me up for a username & password, even though it allows anonymous checkouts.  So I'll have to wait until the admin can help me after all.

I may look into some of those conversion tools to export a project into another VCS as well.  I just couldn't seem to find anything for svn -> svn.

Comment: It turns out that Mercurial has several tools along these lines, including something built in as well as hgsvn.

Comment: @James Graves: you can pass username and password with these options: --sync-username svnsync --sync-password syncpassword